# IronPython programatic string to enum

Tags: python, enums, ironpython

I'm trying to programmatically change a color string to an enum in Python 2.7 (actually IronPython):

```
from System.Drawing import Color

x = "Red"
```

Instead of this:

```
if x == "Red"

    SetColor(Color.Red)
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
SetColor(Color[x])
```

This looks like it would be the correct syntax for Python 3.6, but it is throwing an exception, so I don't know if I made an error or if there is another solution for Python 2.7.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Single Quote because x is variable and by putting single Quote around x you are making it string

```
SetColor(System.Drawing.Color[x])
```

Comment: Sorry, mistyped question. from System.Drawing import Color, SetColor(Color[x]) doesn't work.